# Reverse a stack using recursion (C++)

Tags: c++, recursion, data-structures, stack

Assuming we have a stack data structure containing 5 elements , size[5,4,3,2,1] , write a function to pop and print the last three elements [Top>=2] of the stack in a reverse order using **recursion**.
`input: 1 2 3 4 5`, `output:5 4 3`

My display merhod

```
void trav() { 
  int i;
  if(Top == -1)
    cout<<"stack is empty";
  else
    pop();
  pop();
  for(i=Top; i>=0; i++)
    cout<<"the elements is "<<stack[i];
}
```

Please tell me how to use recursion in this case, the pop part is easy but recursion is my problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your function isn't recursive, so you should probably start by writing a function that calls itself. Don't worry about getting the exact logic at first--can you write a recursive function that prints the stack from top to bottom? Then add in an `n` and you should be done.

Comment: Thanks for replay! I really cant , i dont know how. The reverse part is easy , i can change somethings in for-loop but the question is how to use recursion in this case.

Comment: Maybe do a bit more research then. It's off topic to just ask for the answer--you'll need to make an honest attempt at it. See [how to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). Recursive functions always need to at least call themselves and have a base case that terminates the recursion.